# Is there a way for sails.js to select fields in SQL queries?

Tags: sails.js

I'm new to sails.js. It seems that there is no way for sails.js to make a SQL query for select some fields/columns of a table. The queries seem all "select * ".

Answer (score 9):

I just found a way to make this happen. I am using the 2nd parameter of Model.find

```
Model.find({field: 'value'}, {fields: ['id', 'name']})
```

If you set fields to false it simulates a SELECT *

```
Model.find({field: 'value'}, {fields: false})
```

A complete example:

```
Model.find({field: 'value'}, {fields: ['id', 'name']})
    .paginate({page: 1}, {limit: 10)
    .exec(function(err, results) {
        if(err) {
            res.badRequest('reason');
        }
        res.jsonx(results);
    });
```

Comment: This worked for me after replacing the word "fields" with "select".

Comment: what abount update (it returns full record, can I filter out some filds or record at all from it, I don`t need result of update)

Answer (score 8):

Fields no longer works, you must use select instead.

```
Model.find({field: 'value'}, {select: ['id', 'name']})
  .paginate({page: 1}, {limit: 10})
  .exec(function(err, results) {
    if(err) {
      res.badRequest('reason');
    }
    res.json(results);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no Waterline `SELECT` implementation at the moment, but you can use `Model.query(sqlQuery, callback)` to run a raw SQL query on your database.

For example:

```
User.query('SELECT email, username FROM users WHERE id = 10;', function (err, users) {
  // stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using sails 0.12 and what I figure is: Whenever .populate or .paginate are used(with .find), 'select' should be used. For other cases,'fields'should be used